# Why does it do an initial request even though it's inside of an useEffect with only dependency when the button is clicked

Tags: reactjs

Im learning react and this is some demo code I have written. It does an initial request even though it's inside of an useEffect with dependency. Why does it do that and how can i fix it?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import BasicInfo from "./BasicInfo";

export default function MainInfo(){
    const [searchByName, setSearchByName] = useState('');
    const [pokemonInfo, setPokemonInfo] = useState({});
    const [hasInfo, setHasInfo] = useState(false);
    const [hasPressed, setHasPressed] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        setHasPressed(true);
        console.log(searchByName);
    };
    const changeHandler = (e) =>{
        setSearchByName(e.target.value);
        setHasPressed(false);
    };
    const buttonHandler = (e) =>{
        setHasPressed(oldState => !oldState);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${searchByName}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                setPokemonInfo(data)
                setHasInfo(true)

            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data', error))
    },[hasPressed])
    
    return(
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="input" value={searchByName} onChange={changeHandler}></input>
                <button onClick={buttonHandler}></button>
            </form>
            {hasInfo && pokemonInfo.abilities && (
                <div>
                    <BasicInfo
                        name={pokemonInfo.name}
                        abilities={pokemonInfo.abilities}
                    />
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}
```

What I have tried:

I tried adding state which would change whenever the button is pressed and it's not used for anything else so it doesn't matter if it's true or false. It didn't fix the problem

Comment: `useEffect`'s dependency array doesn't check the truthiness of the items. Add `if (!hasPressed) return` at the beginning of the `useEffect`

Comment: Why are you using an effect at all? Just trigger the fetch on click.

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` triggers on the dependency changes, but the initial run is treated as a change as well.  If you don't want to to the fetch until `hasPressed`, wrap the fetch in an `if`

```
    useEffect(() => {
      if(hasPressed){
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${searchByName}`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                setPokemonInfo(data)
                setHasInfo(true)

            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data', error))
      }
    },[hasPressed])
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the useEffect, you don't need it

just trigger the function onSubmit

and get rid of onClick, and add a type="submit" to your button.

you do not need hasPressed state anymore.

```
    import { useState } from "react";
    import BasicInfo from "./BasicInfo";

    export default function MainInfo() {
    const [searchByName, setSearchByName] = useState("");
    const [pokemonInfo, setPokemonInfo] = useState({});
    const [hasInfo, setHasInfo] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(searchByName);
        fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${searchByName}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            setPokemonInfo(data);
            setHasInfo(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error("Error fetching data", error));
    };
    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        setSearchByName(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
            type="text"
            name="input"
            value={searchByName}
            onChange={changeHandler}
            ></input>
            <button type="submit"></button>
        </form>
        {hasInfo && pokemonInfo.abilities && (
            <div>
            <BasicInfo
                name={pokemonInfo.name}
                abilities={pokemonInfo.abilities}
            />
            </div>
        )}
        </div>
    );
    }
```

Also you don't need hasInfo state, you can replace "hasInfo && pokemonInfo.abilities" by "pokemonInfo && pokemonInfo.abilities"